# Need to call list from API in Retrofit

Tags: android

I have created model classes with review list and reviewwraper.

I am getting error: com.square.http Call does not have any type parameters.

Please help me:)

Thanks

```
 @GET("/movie/{id}/reviews")
 Call<List<Reviews>> getReviews(@Path("id") String id);
```

Model clases without getters and setters:

```
public class Reviews {
@SerializedName("id_review")
private int id;
@SerializedName("author_review")
private String author;
@SerializedName("content_review")
private String content;
@SerializedName("url_review")
private String url;

public class ReviewWraper {

@SerializedName("id")
private int id;
@SerializedName("page")
private int page;
@SerializedName("results")
private List<Reviews> results;
```

Answer (score 0):

> com.square.http Call does not have any type parameters.

you have imported the wrong `Call`. The import has to be from `retrofit2` not from `com.square.http`.

```
import   retrofit2.Call;
```

Comment: Can you give me import name of retrofit 2?Thanks

Comment: import retrofit2.Call;